# Does node's http server have any Content-Length verification for the ReadableStream request

Tags: node.js, http, content-length

Node.js's http server implements a ReadableStream on the Request.

I understand I need to check Content-Length myself to decide if I want to accept a request that long.

However does node do any verification on the ReadableStream to ensure it's valid?

A) If the client closes the connection early and Node hasn't received enough data to satisfy Content-Length, will it `end` the stream and pretend it's ok or will it emit an error?

B) If the client sends more data than Content-Length says will Node emit an error and stop piping data or will it just continue piping data beyond the length?

I'm implementing simple POST body uploads via XHR2 and I want to know if I have to write a custom transform stream to verify the stream myself (so someone can't say they're uploading 2KB but actually upload 20GB that gets written to disk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, since I had to try a test attack against a test script.

Node does have proper handling of the http request stream.

In a normal request when piping req to a file:

- The `end` event will fire directly on `req`
- The `close` event will fire on the writable stream

When you try to write beyond Content-Length:

- `req` will pipe the amount of data defined by Content-Length into the file
- The `end` event will fire directly on `req`
- The `close` event will fire on the writable stream

When you try to under-write and then close the connection:

- The `close` event will fire directly on `req`
- No event will fire on the writable stream (I assume this means you're supposed to treat this as an abort and close and unlink the file yourself)

So piping req to a file after you have verified that Content-Length is acceptable is safe. Node will not write 20GB of data to disk when the Content-Length says 2KB.